# MySQL 1,000's of OR Statements (Good Idea?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a Twitter application that grabs a users entire following and gets their specific id *Ex: 1223455*

I also have a huge database full of rows that contain a specific Twitter id... Look at the examples in rows...

```
|1| 122345   |
|2| 2232144  |
|3| 99653222 |
|4| 123232   |
|5| 2321323  |
|6| 3121322  |
```

The problem is we all know that Twitter is all about more and more followers (1,000's), and I was wonder is this is a good MySQL query to run potentially up to 20 times in one script run...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE twitterID='132323' OR twitterId='23123' OR twitterId='23123' OR twitterId='23123' OR twitterId='23123' OR twitterId='23123' OR twitterId='23123' OR twitterId='23123
```

And on and on and on and on... There could potentially be over 1,000 OR statements in a single query (and a similar query like this could be called 20 times)

This doesn't seem like a very good programming practice, but I haven't heard of another way...??

Comment: Have you used **IN** keyword?

Comment: I see you accepted the answer with the "in" list.  This is perfectly reasonable, but you should consider the version that keeps the ids in a table and uses a join (or in).  At some point, you may run into compilation issues and even query length issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `in` specifier:

```
Select * from table where twitterid in (123,456,789,...)
```

Comment: Is this still a good idea though... Will it be incredibly slow?

Comment: do you have an index for that field _twitterID_ ?

Comment: It will be faster than the ors. Only other suggestion i can think of is using a view if you consistently look for groups of numbers.

Comment: No I don't have an index... Would that help?

Comment: But it is not auto increment and I already set up and id column

Comment: Thats ok. You can still Make an index on that column, doesnt have to be an auto increment. Just dont assign it as unique or primary.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very bad idea indeed.  MySQL doesn't do a good job with optimizing OR statements.

You'd be *far* better off using a JOIN or something like this

```
WHERE twitterId IN (
      select * 
        from followers
       where followee = whatever
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t1
WHERE twitterID 
      IN (select twitterID 
            from twitterIDsTable t2
           where t1.twitterID = t2.twitterID)--for performance
```